# how can i have a button do multiple things in opposite

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

```js
barsButton.onclick = function xtranslate(){
    aside[0].style.transform = "translateX(0px)"
    stories.style.marginLeft = "0px";
}
```

how can i click the button twice so the next time it transforms x to 250px ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable and update its value using [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var toTranslate = '0px';
barsButton.onclick = function xtranslate(){
  aside[0].style.transform = `translateX(${toTranslate})`;
  stories.style.marginLeft = "0px";
  toTranslate = toTranslate == '0px' ? '250px' : '0px';
}
```

Comment: thanks i am not so good with javascript what does the ? mark means in here

Comment: @S.alhaider, that is *Conditional (ternary) operator*...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator